# Django in query

Tags: python, django

When using django querysets. Is is possible to use the `in` operation, or another method, to maintain a one-to-one mapping between objects.

> For example I would like:
>
> `id_list = [12,2,33]`
> `Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)`
>
> To preserve order and return `None` when one of the ids is missing, eg:
>
> `ret = [Foo(id=12), None, Foo(id=33)]`
>
> where `Foo(id=2)` doesn't exist.

At present, the only method I have of doing this is to create an intermediate dictionary.
For example:

```
map = {o.id: o for o in Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)}
ret = [map.get(id, None) for id in id_list]
```

Comment: You could also add a ModelMethod such that something like `ret = [Foo.objects.get_or_none(id=id) for id in id_list]` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to fetch the instances in the order, and needing to returning `None` for missing objects makes it even trickier.

You can use [`in_bulk()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) to simplify your code slightly.

```
bulk_foos = Foo.objects.in_bulk(id_list)  # returns a dict of foos, keyed on id
ordered_foos = [bulk_foos.get(foo_id, None) for foo_id in id_list)]
```